# JENKINS -- sleep: command not found

Tags: shell, jenkins, cygwin

I want to run a shell command on Jenkins by delaying every 5 seconds. Following is the command :

```
cd /cygdrive/c/path/project_name

./scheduler.sh &
```

While in `scheduler.sh` is :

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep="/bin/sleep"
(sleep 5 && ./to_run.sh) &
(sleep 10 && ./to_run.sh) & 
(sleep 15 && ./to_run.sh) &
(sleep 20 && ./to_run.sh) & 
(sleep 25 && ./to_run.sh) &
(sleep 30 && ./to_run.sh) & 
(sleep 35 && ./to_run.sh) & 
(sleep 40 && ./to_run.sh) & 
(sleep 45 && ./to_run.sh) & 
(sleep 50 && ./to_run.sh) & 
(sleep 55 && ./to_run.sh) & 
(sleep 60 && ./to_run.sh) &
```

which will run `to_run.sh` every 5 seconds. The `to_run.sh` containing script to run the python project :

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH="$PATH;$PYTHON_PATH"

/cygdrive/c/path/venv/Scripts/activate & cd /cygdrive/c/path/project_name& python whatever.py runserver

echo "SUCCESS RUN ALL PYTHON SCRIPTS!"
```

However, I'm getting this error from Jenkins even tho build is successful :

```
Started by timer
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Oncore temp table
$ C:\cygwin64\bin\cygpath -w C:\cygwin64\bin\sh
[Oncore temp table] $ C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe -xe C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins4700784491498255011.sh
+ cd /cygdrive/c/path/project_name
+ ./scheduler.sh
./scheduler.sh: line 3: sleep: command not found
./scheduler.sh: line 3: sleep: command not found
./scheduler.sh: line 3: sleep: command not found
./scheduler.sh: line 3: sleep: command not found
./scheduler.sh: line 3: sleep: command not found
./scheduler.sh: line 3: sleep: command not found
./scheduler.sh: line 3: sleep: command not found
./scheduler.sh: line 3: sleep: command not found
./scheduler.sh: line 3: sleep: command not found
./scheduler.sh: line 3: sleep: command not found
./scheduler.sh: line 3: sleep: command not found
./scheduler.sh: line 3: sleep: command not found
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I already set cygwin on Jenkins :

[image]

Please help!

Comment: Your PATH does not seem to include /usr/bin. Either fix this (`PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH`), or invoke `sleep` explicitly via `/usr/bin/sleep`. BTW, you also assign a **shell variable** named `sleep`, which you never use. Is this intended?

Comment: @user1934428 I mentioned the unused `$sleep` shell variable in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
PATH="$PATH;$PYTHON_PATH"
```

appends `$PYTHON_PATH` to your `$PATH`, but it uses a semicolon as the separator. On Cygwin, `sleep` is in `/usr/bin` or `/bin` (they're actually the same directory), and in the environment in which you command runs, one of those is probably the last directory in your `$PATH`. So the last element of your `$PATH` might be something like `/usr/bin;/your/python/path`, which doesn't exist.

Cygwin, like Unix or Linux, separates elements of `$PATH` with colons, not semicolons. (I know Windows uses semicolons; Cygwin hides that from you.) Try this:

```
PATH="$PATH:$PYTHON_PATH"
```

Also, this:

```
sleep="/bin/sleep"
(sleep 5 && ./to_run.sh) &
```

sets a shell variable named `$sleep` to `/bin/sleep` but that doesn't make it a command name. `sleep 5` still searches for the `sleep` command in your `$PATH` (which you've already messed up).

Normally either `/bin` or `/usr/bin` will already be in your `$PATH`, so just invoke `sleep 5` directly and it will find it. Drop the `sleep="/bin/sleep"` line; it's not necessary.

But if you did want to specify where the `sleep` command is, you'd want to use a shell function or alias, not a variable setting. For example, you could do:

```
alias sleep=/bin/sleep
sleep 5
```

but as I said it shouldn't be necessary.

Incidentally, a simpler way to run your command every 5 seconds is:

```
for i in {1..12} ; do
    sleep 5
    ./to_run.sh &
done
```

Comment: I change `;` to `:` and use the `for` loop solution. I'm still getting the same error. sleep command not found

Comment: `/bin/sleep` belongs to `coreutils-8.26-2` package that should be installed by default as it belongs to the `Base` category

Comment: I added `alias` as front and it worked out. But now I'm getting `python` cmd not found. I've already set the PYTHON_PATH though... What else i did wrong

Comment: @xixi What is the value of `$PATH` before you update it? You *should* be able to just invoke `sleep` directly without using an alias, variable, or function. I think something has messed up your `$PATH`.